# Maven compile error - Package does not exist

Tags: java, compilation, maven-3

I'm starting a microservices project, based on the MVC architecture, where the MODEL part of it will be used by all of the microservices. For that I've created a project (HabilWeb_Commons) with the Model part of the webapp and with some classes that will be common for all of the other microservices.
The problem happens when I try to add the HabilWeb_Commons project to another, using Maven.
Below is a snippet of my `pom.xml` file:

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>internal-repo</id>
    <url>file://${project.basedir}/lib</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
    <artifactId>HabilWeb_Commons</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <type>jar</type>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

In every reference to any of the classes from the `HabilWeb_Commons` project, when I try to build the microservice, the following errors happen:

```
br/com/koinonia/habil/controller/EmpresaController.java:[8,35] package br.com.koinonia.habil.model does not exist
br/com/koinonia/habil/controller/EmpresaController.java:[19,59] cannot find symbol
symbol: class Empresa
```

Class `Empresa` is created in HabilWeb_Commons project, in the following package path: `br.com.koinonia.habil.model`

I Have absolutely no idea what I'm doing wrong, since I already tried this approach with other projects with no problem.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem creating a maven based project, with multiple modules, HabilWeb_Commons being one of this modules. Works like a charm.